# Commenting and uncommenting shortcut in bluefish editor

Tags: html, comments, shortcut

I'm using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to comment in Bluefish Editor. But I don't know the shortcut to uncomment it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://www.unc.edu/~whitews/bluefish/book.html

Comment: @ punter: Sir, I couldn't find any shortcut for comment & uncomment in http://www.unc.edu/~whitews/bluefish/book.html

Comment: there is some info about Modifying shortcut keys. . .
it might be helpful . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Alt+Ctrl+c, you can use Shift+Ctrl+c to comment in bluefish editor. You can use the same for uncommenting also. Shift+ctrl+c is for toggle comment.